# intellij com.mysql.jdbc.Driver issues, tried multiple methods

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I've been searching for more than a day now on this simple problem. This is my first time using Intellij/Android Studio as I come from using Eclipse. The issue I'm having is that the project can't find my driver. I've done this multiple times, usually you would just have to make sure that the mysql-connector.jar is referenced/added to the project. However, Intellij is not so simple in this regard. First, I am using the free version and not the ultimate, so I do not have the database tools option but luckily, there is a database navigator plugin. I add it and set my connections. I use the built-in driver as shown

[image: database navigator - connection info]

and my code is the following:

```
private static Connection connection = null;
private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String url, user, password = "";
private static String server = "localhost";

public LoginDataSource() {
    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    setDatabase(server);
    try {
        Class.forName(driver); // <-- fails here
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error due to

```
     W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
```

I keep looking and some say to add the connector jar as a maven dependency. I do that as shown:

[image: maven]

and I add it here too

[image: Libraries]

I run the application again and still same error. So next I go back to database navigator and edit the driver to external and select the regular driver as shown:

[image: database navigator - driver]

I run the application again and still the same error... I am at a lost. I don't know what to do, and it would be really great if someone could tell me. 
This is my external libraries if it helps, the mysql connector is not shown here

[image: external libraries]

I tried multiple ways and I know there are VERY similar threads on this but believe me, I have tried and I still can't figure it out on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help. First, remove your previous MySQL driver dependencies, to start from scratch. Then, you need to declare a dependency in your "build.gradle" file:

`// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'`

After you add this line to the script, refresh the gradle dependencies.

Then, try to load the driver again, but note that `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is deprecated now, use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

I will answer your questions if this small instruction fails.

Comment: I pasted it as instructed in the dependency block like so.

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'

I then got a warning 'build.gradle: configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'...

I ran the progam and got this error message

E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList

No luck unfortunately.

Comment: Oh right, replace the "compile" word with "implementation".

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't it
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\Esau\IdeaProjects\OnTheRocks\app\build.gradle': 40: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
  In case you tried to configure a property named 'https', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
   @ line 40, column 5.
         implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'
         ^


Do I leave the https:// commented out or am I supposed to put implementation on that line too?

Comment: Try removing the "https..." string and leave just the "implementation..." one.

Comment: That didn't work either. It's okay, thanks for trying.